# Does Possible To Import 1.4 GB SQL File Using WAMP SERVER

Tags: magento-1.9, database, sql, file-upload

I need to Import 1.4 GB SQL file to Wamp, when I try to import I get error **[zip_extension.lib.php]**

How can I import large size of SQL file to Wamp Server.

Answer (score 1):

For large DB you can use command line to import

```
c:\mysql\bin\> mysql -u username -ppassword database_name < filename.sql
```

Or you can increase limit

**wamp\apache2\bin\php.ini**

```
find:
post_max_size = 8M

change to:
post_max_size = 1500M // 1.5GB


find:
upload_max_filesize = 2M

change to:
upload_max_filesize = 1500M  // 1.5GB
```

IF that does not work

**config.inc.php (PhpMyAdmin)**

```
$cfg['MemoryLimit'] = '128M';
```

Comment: Not working what you mentioned, my sql size 1.4 gb

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a server question than a Magento question but, essentially you are hitting the limits that are set by default. You need to modify your:

**php.ini**

```
post_max_size=1500M
upload_max_filesize=1500M
max_execution_time = 3600 // 1 hour time in seconds increase depending on your servers performance
```

**my.ini**

```
max_allowed_packet = 1500M
```

There are other ways to get a large database imported, can be done through the command line using `mysql.exe`, Google has plenty of information on how to achieve that.

Comment: not working.....

Answer (score 0):

Using command prompt,we can import sql file;

Assume that **your wamp is installed at C drive**`(c:)`.

and **`mysql.exe`** located at `c:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql[MYSQLVERSION]\`.

First open cmd run  the command:

- **`cd c:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql[MYSQLVERSION]\`**
- **`mysql -u root -p [Yourdatabasename]<[YouSQLFileloCation]\[SQLFIlename].sql`**

Hope this will resolve your issue

Comment: i get error like, 'mysql' is not recognized  as an internal or external command

Comment: my command::  mysql -u root -p [Yourdatabasename]<[YouSQLFileloCation]\[SQLFIlename].sql

Comment: pls join chat  http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50711/sql-error

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50711/sql-error

Comment: does matter mq sql version regard you command